# how form upload can display? when i run this file

Tags: php, upload

I have a php script like the following

```
<?php
if($_FILES['img']['type'] != "image/gif") {
    echo "<center><br>param name: img<br>directory file /challenge/ex";
    exit;
}
$uploaddir = 'ex/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['img']['name']);
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
} else {
    echo "File uploading failed.\n";
}
?>
<center>
<br><br>
    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" size="20" name="img" />
        <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload" />
    </form>
```

but, form upload and button can't display, when i run this file

Comment: Do you mean that the button does not show on the form?

Comment: form upload and button can't display, when i run this file

Comment: Or are you asking how to show the user a message saying the "Upload has worked"?

Comment: Is that ALL the code from this script file?

Comment: yes that all the code from script file

Comment: Add [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/) to the
top of your file(s) _while testing_ right after your opening PHP tag for example. 
Even if you are developing on a server configured as LIVE you will now see any errors. 
`<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Or, are you wanting to show the uploaded file; is that what this is really about? @buayalaut

Comment: yes, i already add the error reporting, no, i want show form upload button, not show the uploaded file

Answer (score 0):

this mostly happen when there is a php error,
try to add these three lines before the second line :

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

so it will be :

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
if($_FILES['img']['type'] != "image/gif") {
    echo "<center><br>param name: img<br>directory file /challenge/ex";
    exit;
}
$uploaddir = 'ex/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['img']['name']);
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
} else {
    echo "File uploading failed.\n";
}
?>
<center>
<br><br>
    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" size="20" name="img" />
        <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload" />
    </form>
```

and hopefully some error will show up so we can fix it.

Comment: new problem                                                                                                          
Notice: Undefined index: img in /home/buayalau/domains/co/public_html/challenge/up2.php on line 5

Comment: try check the method after display errors line with if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){ and close it before closing php tag

Comment: if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')